# Refresh previous screen after editing the state and going back

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

Alright, I know there's a lot of speculation online about how this should be done, but I'm not happy about most of them or they are outdated :)

This is a simplified representation of my setup:

```
// Navigator
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
<Stack.Navigator
    initialRouteName={"A"}
>
    <Stack.Screen
        name={"A"}
        component={A}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
        name={"B"}
        component={B}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
        name={"C"}
        component={C}
    />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Redux is my state manager of choice and it's working fine for my 3 dummy screens
Here's a dummy state and reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    items: [
        {prop: "a"},
        {prop: "b"},
        {prop: "c"},
    ]
}
const dummyReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "EDIT":
            const dummyEdit = state.items.pop();
            dummyEdit.prop = "c (edited)";
            return {
               items = [...state.items, dummyEdit]
            }
    }
}
```

And here are my very innovative screens

```
// Class A
render() {
    return <A>
        <ListView ... data={state.items} />
    </A>
}

// Class B
render() {
    return <B>
        <Text>state.item.prop</Text>
    </B>
}

// Class C
render() {
    return <C>
        <Input value={state.item.prop}
            onChangeText={text => dispatch({type: EDIT})}
        ></Input>
    </C>
}
```

So screen `A` is just a list that navigates to screen `B` which displays the item properties.
On screen `B` you can edit that item, which takes you to Screen `C`.
When you edit the item on screen `C`, the reducer updates the state. After that you `navigation.goBack()` to screen `B`.

All screens are connected to the same reducer and state.
When I place a breakpoint in the render function of screen `B`, I can see the state is indeed updated right after the `C`'s input `onTextChanged`

**What I (think I) know**

- On screen B, this doesn't help: `shouldComponentUpdate() {return true;}`
- Redux compares object lazily so `prevState.items === state.items` is true and the screen doesn't update
- Even though the `render` function is being called, that doesn't mean the screen will be updated
- I can `navigation.dispatch(StackActions.pop(2)); navigation.navigate("B");` to update screen `B` but this seems far-fetched and it leaves you with a back transition animation

**Packages**

```
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "^0.61.5",
"react-navigation": "^4.2.2",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.1.1",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.9",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.1.1",
```

Hopefully some of you recognize the problem I'm facing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure to follow your concern. It only updates the state when you do the navigation pop and navigate? Is the reducer being triggered correctly?

Comment: @IanVasco In my experience only the active screen is updated (screen C in this case). The reducer is triggered correctly because I can place a breakpoint in the render function of screen B (the previous screen) and see that the props have been updated correctly according to the changes made in screen C. I tried both `navigation.goBack()` and `navigation.pop()`, but by then the state would have already been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I managed to figure out what was wrong. I was wrong to assume that the problem was the `StackNavigator`
My screen `B` is a lot more complex than the example I gave, so I'll add some details.

```
// Class B
render() {
    return <B>
        <CustomTextContainer data={state.item}>
            <CustomText data={state.item.prop1} />
            <CustomText data={state.item.prop2} />
        </CustomTextContainer>
    </B>
}
```

Both `CustomTextContainer` and `CustomText` are connected to the store and they both have a `shouldComponentUpdate` function.
Apparently, when the container's `shouldComponentUpdate` returns false, the children's `shouldComponentUpdate` function never gets called.

This was my mistake. I've read that when the child is connected to the store, it should receive it's props directly regardless of it's parent. That's not the case.